# SAS: How to detect the date format in SAS from UNIX folder?

Tags: sas

I have access to a linux directory where it contains multiple folders with various names.
Eg.
01312019
19990131
europe_1
johncena

Based on the 4 samples above, only the first and second line are valid date format (MMDDYYYY & YYYYMMDD).

What I want to achieve is to identify and flag the folder that is having the date format that I want, for example, MMDDYYYY. Once identified, I will write a set of rules to further process it.

My script below is already able to scan for the directory.

```
    data allfilenames;
    length fref $8 fname $200;
    did = filename(fref,"&ROOT./&Directory.");
    did = dopen(fref);
    do i = 1 to dnum(did);
      fname = dread(did,i);
      output;
    end;
    did = dclose(did);
    did = filename(fref);
    keep fname;
run;

data folderonly;
    set allfilenames;
    if count(fname,'.') >0 then delete;
run;
```

However, now I am stuck on how to check the folder name for its date format. Again, it is possible that folder names might not contain a valid date format at all, or contain date format differently (YYYYMMDD or MMDDYYYY).

Is there any guide that I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data folderonly ;
  input @1 fname $20.;
datalines ;
01122021
12312021
20210901
blahblah
;
run ;

data check ;
  set folderonly ;
  if input(fname,??mmddyy8.) then valid_mmddyy = 1 ;
run ;
```

The ?? before the informat suppresses any errors due to data which doesn't match the informat.